# How to create a counter with a button in Domino Notes

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotus-formula, domino-designer-eclipse

I want a button and a field. Where when the button is pressed it +1 into the field. So a counter basically. Is this possible? What would be the code behind the button and the field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add

- a field "Counter" of type "Number" with a Default Value formula `0` and
- a button "add 1" with formula `FIELD Counter := Counter + 1`

to your form.

Comment: This is perfect thankyou, now is there a way to program the button to hide if it has been pressed. I would like to hide it forever so the user will never be able to see it again? So once pressed there is no going back?

Comment: The answer is in your other question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31119628/2065611 . You have to memorize per document which user pressed the button already.